# Adding time to date time column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dateadd

I am trying to view a column by adding  5 hours 30 min to a date time column  using SQL Server using `dateadd` but it is not working

```
dateadd(hour, 5, dateadd(minute, 30, visit_start_time))
```

`visit_start_time` is a `datetime` column

Comment: `but it is not working` ... _what_ is not working?  Can you add sample data to your question to make it reproducible?

Comment: Actually I Just realized your query should work in sql server. Which version of sql server you are using and what's not working?

Answer (score 2):

There is multiple ways to do this:

- Using time literal

```sql
DECLARE @table table(a datetime)
insert into @table values ('2020-02-02T10:00:00.000')


SELECT a, a + CAST('05:30:00' AS DATETIME) FROM @table
```

| a | updateddate |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-02-02 10:00:00.000 | 2020-02-02 15:30:00.000 |

- Using DATEADD

```sql
DECLARE @table table(a datetime)
insert into @table values ('2020-02-02T10:00:00.000')

SELECT DATEADD(minute,30,DATEADD(hour,5,a))  from @table
SELECT DATEADD(minute,330,a)  from @table
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead add 330 minutes (equivalent of 5 hours thirty minutes) as below:

```
Dateadd(minute,330,visit_start_time)
```

Or you can do it as you were trying:

```
Dateadd(hour,5,  Dateadd(minute,30,visit_start_time))
```

Actually I Just realized your query should work in sql server. Which version of sql server you are using and what's not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
DATEADD(n,330,visit_start_time)
```

`n` (the first parameter) is a shorthand for `minute`; 330 minutes = 5 hours (*60) + 30 minutes.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.